# laravel 4 authentication check always returns false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm making an application in laravel 4 and I've run into a problem.

So far I have tried to make an authentication system. I followed several tutorials but none of them seem to work. Possibly because the tutorial is already outdated (laravel is evolving constantly).

Here's my situation:

I have a login form, this form authenticates the user. And it works just fine, this is the code in my routes.php file.

```
Route::post('login', function () {
    $user = array(
        'e-mail' => Input::get('E-mail'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );
    if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
        return Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('flash_notice', 'You are successfully logged in.');
    }

    // authentication failure! lets go back to the login page
    return Redirect::route('login')
        ->with('flash_error', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect.')
        ->withInput();
});
```

So when I log in I go to the home page and the message is displayed, no problems there.
In my view I have following code (I use blade for this).

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ URL::to('home') }}">Home</a></li>
            @if(Auth::check())
                <li><a href="{{ URL::to('profile') }}">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ URL::to('logout', 'Logout ('.Auth::user()->e-mail.')') }}">Logout</a></li>
            @else
                <li><a href="{{ URL::to('login') }}">Login</a></li>
            @endif
        </ul>
```

The problem is that no matter what the Auth::check() returns false.
I have researched this problem for several hours and don't know where to continue...

In the User model the getKey() method returns null, so I thought my database might be wrong. But the data is being fetched perfectly.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This clearly isn't PHP.

Comment: Yes it is... Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Sami, it is just templates. Mike, could you look is there any cookies in your browser?

Comment: there is a cookie, "laravel_session"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As it turns out this was a silly mistake.
Laravel defines a default primary key as 'id' in smallcaps.
The id I used in my database was defined as 'ID'.

I fixed this by changing my field names in my database.
Another option is to define

```
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
```

in your model...

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

`$user = array(
    'e-mail' => Input::get('E-mail'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
);`

Behind the scene, Eloquent or Fluent Query Builder would try to fetch using a query equivalent to:

`$user = User::where('e-mail', '=', ?)->first();`

This would be all good if you have a field `e-mail`, but this would cause issue with Eloquent as `Auth::user()->e-mail` became an invalid syntax.

Comment: I changed the "e-mail" field to "username" but the same problem occurs. I am completely new to laravel, so I might have misunderstood your message.
I am indeed working with eloquent though.

By the way, this is the tutorial I based my work on:
http://laravelbook.com/laravel-user-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the route is under the web middleware group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'] , function() {
}
```

Auth doesnt work if the page has no web middleware